# What are the Access startup properties that can be changed using VBA

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have an app that uses the following procedure to change some of the Current DB properties.

```
Public Sub SetStartupOptions(propname As String, propdb As Variant, prop As Variant)
On Error GoTo Err_SetStartupOptions

  'Set passed startup property.

  'some of the startup properties you can use...
  ' "StartupShowDBWindow", DB_BOOLEAN, False
  ' "StartupShowStatusBar", DB_BOOLEAN, False
  ' "AllowBuiltinToolbars", DB_BOOLEAN, False
  ' "AllowFullMenus", DB_BOOLEAN, False
  ' "AllowBreakIntoCode", DB_BOOLEAN, False
  ' "AllowSpecialKeys", DB_BOOLEAN, False
  ' "AllowBypassKey", DB_BOOLEAN, False

  Dim dbs As Object

  Dim prp As Object

  Set dbs = CurrentDb


    If propname = "DBOpen" Then
        dbs.Properties("AllowBreakIntoCode") = prop
        dbs.Properties("AllowSpecialKeys") = prop
        dbs.Properties("AllowBypassKey") = prop
        dbs.Properties("AllowFullMenus") = prop
        dbs.Properties("StartUpShowDBWindow") = prop
    Else
        dbs.Properties(propname) = prop
   End If

  Set dbs = Nothing

  Set prp = Nothing

Exit_SetStartupOptions:
    Exit Sub

Err_SetStartupOptions:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 3270

           Set prp = dbs.CreateProperty(propname, propdb, prop)

           Resume Next

          Case Else
              Dim ErrAns As Integer, ErrMsg As String
              If ErrChoice = vbYesNoCancel Then
                  ErrMsg = Err.Description & ": " & Str(Err.Number) & vbNewLine & "Press 'Yes' to resume next;" & vbCrLf & _
                   "'No' to Exit Procedure." & vbCrLf & "or 'Cancel' to break into code"
             Else
                  ErrMsg = Err.Description & ": " & Str(Err.Number) & vbNewLine & "Press 'Yes' to resume next;" & vbCrLf & _
                    "'No' to Exit Procedure."
             End If
            ErrAns = MsgBox(ErrMsg, _
            vbCritical + vbQuestion + ErrChoice, "SetStartupOptions")
            If ErrAns = vbYes Then
                Resume Next
            ElseIf ErrAns = vbCancel Then
                On Error GoTo 0
                Resume
            Else
                Resume Exit_SetStartupOptions
            End If
    End Select

End Sub
```

procedure can be used to add and set values for DB.properties,  These are the properties that are set in the Access options screen. I have a limited list of property names but, does anyone know where I can find the full list of properties that are recognized? ( i.e. the startup form name, start up ribbon name,... )

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb258165(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: There are some notes here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907255/hide-access-options/11227830#11227830 as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can list all of the properties for the database that exist at the time you run the code using a very simple procedure as seen here.

```
Public Sub ListDBProps()
    Dim db As Database
    Dim prp As Property

    Set db = CurrentDb

    For Each prp In db.Properties
        Debug.Print prp.Name
    Next prp

End Sub
```

There are a couple of gotcha's in this. Notice I said "that exist at the time you run the code". That is, Access creates properties for the database (and presumably other objects as well) on an "as needed" basis. For instance, when you compile the database into, what used to be called an MDE, now an ACCDE, Access will add a new property of Type "Text" [10] named "MDE" with a value of "T". There are a couple of properties in the list you provided that fall into this category as well, such as "AllowBypassKey" and "AllowBreakIntoCode".

Here is the list that I got when I ran this code on a simple database I opened up:
    Name
    Connect
    Transactions
    Updatable
    CollatingOrder
    QueryTimeout
    Version
    RecordsAffected
    ReplicaID
    DesignMasterID
    Connection
    ANSI Query Mode
    Themed Form Controls
    AccessVersion
    NavPane Category
    UseMDIMode
    ShowDocumentTabs
    Build
    CheckTruncatedNumFields
    ProjVer
    StartUpShowDBWindow
    StartUpShowStatusBar
    AllowShortcutMenus
    AllowFullMenus
    AllowBuiltInToolbars
    AllowToolbarChanges
    AllowSpecialKeys
    UseAppIconForFrmRpt
    AllowDatasheetSchema
    Show Values Limit
    Show Values in Indexed
    Show Values in Non-Indexed
    Show Values in Remote
    Auto Compact
    DesignWithData
    Picture Property Storage Format
    NavPane Closed
    NavPane Width
    NavPane View By
    NavPane Sort By
    Track Name AutoCorrect Info
    Perform Name AutoCorrect
    HasOfflineLists

You can add the Type property to your output easily enough. It is an integer value corresponding to the DataTypeEnum enumeration. The Value property of the Property can be a little more tricky. Usually it's a value that can be easily converted to a string value but there are a couple that cause a runtime error when you try to print them out or store them in a String variable. A little error handling in a small function can handle that with no trouble.

My example was run on an ACCDB in Microsoft Access 2007.

Enjoy . . . Doug