# Customize Ribbon to Suppress Backstage with Access 2013

Tags: xml, ms-access-2013

I am using the recommended XML to create a custom ribbon that suppresses the Backstage options on my Access 2013 app. I don't want the end user to be able to do anything with the database that I don't dictate. This code worked for Access 2010, but when used in Access 2013, I can still see the "New" and "SaveAs" options on the backstage tab despite the commands that seem relevant to them below. Can anyone recommend the tweak I need?
Thanks!

[Hide Access Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907255/hide-access-options/11227830#11227830)

```
<button idMso="FileSave" visible="false"/>
<tab idMso ="TabNew" visible="false"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem....found this and now I have a blank Backstage View.

```
<backstage>
  <!-- Info -->
  <tab idMso ="TabInfo" visible="false"/> 
  <!-- New -->
  <tab idMso ="TabOfficeStart" visible="false"/> 
  <!-- Open -->
  <tab idMso="TabRecent" visible="false"/>
  <!-- Save -->
  <button idMso="FileSave" visible="false"/>
  <!-- Save As -->
  <tab idMso="TabSave" visible="false"/>
  <!-- Print -->
  <tab idMso ="TabPrint" visible="false"/>
  <!-- Close -->
  <button idMso="FileCloseDatabase" visible="true"/>
  <!-- Account -->
  <tab idMso="TabHelp" visible="false"/>
  <!-- Options -->
  <button idMso="ApplicationOptionsDialog" visible="false"/>
</backstage>
```