# Disable Access 2013 navigation pane options

Tags: ms-access, drop-down-menu, vba, ms-access-2013

I need to prevent users from modifying underlying tables and code in an Access form.

I found [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907255/hide-access-options) which works exactly as described. The form design is permanently hidden and Access Options are disabled.

However, if I click the dropdown arrow by the navigation pane header and select anything in Navigate to Category, I can still view (but not edit) all underlying tables, queries, and forms.

Is there a way to change or remove options in this menu?

[image: Navigate to Category menu]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
DoCmd.NavigateTo "acNavigationCategoryObjectType"
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWindowHide
```

The code should be initiated on the form load event. If you are using some sort of login system you might want to enable it for all users bar the DB Admin.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Are there any ways to do it without a macro? When I open the file, macros are disabled by the security settings in Access until I manually enable content. The menu is still accessible until then.

Comment: You can added it to a login form if you have one, or whichever form you have set to open first. Failing that you can add it to the Autoexec module.

Comment: But all modules and macros are disabled on startup ([example](http://f.tqn.com/y/databases/1/S/_/B/SecurityWarning.jpg)). My main form opens on startup, but the navigation pane will not be hidden until macros are enabled. I wonder if hiding the pane is possible to do using XML as well.