# How to prevent the end-user from viewing back-end data from front-end in an MS Access 2010 application?

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have an Access Application that is split into a back-end where the data tables are stored, and a front-end where the UI and business logic resides. I what to distribute the application without allowing the end-user to view the data tables in the back-end through the front-end.
I compile the front-end into an .accde file and disable "Display Navigation Pane" and the "Use Access Special Keys" options. Further, I have a VBA code that executes to disable these options on exit so that if the end-user enables them, then they get disabled by the code. However, if the user enables the options then kills MS Access from the task manager, then when the front-end is launched again, the user can view the Navigation Pane.

What is the best way to protect my application so that the user can only access forms and reports and not the underlying data?

Comment: I haven't found a method to this yet.

Answer (score 2):

Do not know whether this might be the answer you are looking for but you might consider migrating your data to MSDE/SQL Server Express. They offer user-level security on tables and queries.

Answer (score 1):

If you disable the shift-key for opening the database, the user should not be able to change your settings. Note that it is possible to lock you yourself out of the db this way.

See also: [MS Access Start up Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683216/ms-access-start-up-properties/7687070#7687070)

If proctecting your data is critical, you may need t look at a database other than Access, with Access, you can protect from accidental tampering, but really malicious tampering will get through.

Comment: My concern is the malicious tampering. I'm not an expert in MS Access. But I have spent a few hours searching for a solution to my problem with no luck.

Comment: As I said, if your data is critical, you need a server and something like SQL Server.

Comment: @Fionnuala If they move to SQL Server would this prevent the user for viewing all rows of a table ? I mean it could be possible that each user should have crud to specific rows. Is this beyond access scope ?

Comment: SQL Server allows you to create views, and MS Access allows you to link views. You can create Roles in SQL Server, grant permissions to roles and add members to roles.