# Enabling developer view of Access DB?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2003

MS Access isn't my primary area of knowledge. Therefor my question is probably not specific enough. Nevertheless.

We have a custom-built MS Access application we'd like to change slightly, for example add  the year 2012 to a certain control.

**As may MS Access app, this one hides the developer view of the database**. Recently - while the app posted a error message during shutdown -, the developer view got exposed. Unfortunately, below to error dialog box, which by a click of OK terminated MS Access.

I assume, that there is a standard way to bring up the developer of such a database. Could someone povide hints?

**Please don't provide links pointing to cracking software. I'm solely interested in the standard / legal way.**

Comment: Are you referring to an an Access database with a .accde extension (executable only) file?

Comment: I knew, that my knowledge is not current regarding MS Access ;-) No, a conventional one. One that requires MS Access to load and run the DB-file [MDB?].

Comment: If it is an MDB, then it was written using a previous version (before 2007). Remou's answer should help you.

Comment: @rontornambe Thx! Yes, the database was written using a previous MS Access release. Unfortunately, IT told a college, that the old one won't run with the current Access release. I'm going to jump in and help out. Let's see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you are dealing with mdb/accdb, rather than mde/accde, it is possible that holding the shift key down while opening the database will enable the disabled menus. Keep the shift key held down until the database is fully opened. In some cases, the shift key override is disabled, but there are ways around this also.

Once the database is open, press alt+F11 to open the code window.

If the shift key bypass has been disabled, life gets a little more difficult, start by reading [MS Access Start up Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683216/ms-access-start-up-properties/7687070#7687070)

Comment: Thank you! Hm, something comes back from the bar right rear of my brain ;-)